# Java "e" cannot be resolved as a variable in a keyPressed function

Tags: java, function, keypress

I am trying to write a Java application that will listen to key input from the user. This is my code...

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class DashExplorerMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DashExplorerMain dashExplorer = new DashExplorerMain();
        dashExplorer.keyPressed(e);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        switch( keyCode ) { 
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                // handle up 
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                // handle down 
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                // handle left
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT :
                // handle right
                System.out.println("-");
                break;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

When I try to compile my code, I am getting the following error...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: e cannot be resolved to a variable
    at DashExplorerMain.main(DashExplorerMain.java:11)
```

Could you please help me understand the problem.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen with this line?  `DashExplorer.keyPressed(e);`

Comment: The convention in Java is to start variables with lowercase letter. Using an uppercase letter like you did will make many people think it is a static method call on a class.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth i believe i am trying to initialize the function in the main() function so that it will work when i run the code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a Key Listener that actually listens for the key events and calls the appropriate method. Normally you would attach it to a component (e.g. JTextField, JPanel, etc.) using the `addKeyListener()` method.

```
DashExplorer.keyPressed(e);
```

is using a variable that hasn't been declared.

Check out [this tutorial from oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) about implementing a key listener.

Comment: i know this is probably the solution, but i am not advanced enough to understand. All i am trying to do is have it so that when i push the right key, it prints a dash. That is what i want to do for now. but once i get that to work than i will elaborate and make the program more in depth.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're writing to a console application at the moment? If so - it is difficult to capture keypresses such as right-arrow in a console application as you have to press enter before input is returned. If you are creating a swing application, it is easy to do following the link I posted in the answer

Comment: yes...dang that sucks...i was at school today and thought i would practice by doing something in the console..ya know something simple...i dont even know how to code with swing...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this line:

```
DashExplorer.keyPressed(e);
```

attempts to referred to a variable that is not in scope / not declared.

I don't understand what you are trying to do in the `main` method.  (Is it a test harness?)

The obvious "fix" would be to use `new KeyEvent(...)` to create a key event at that point, but that requires you to understand the constructor arguments.  And unless this is a test harness it doesn't make much sense to do that.